# Use JSTL forEach loop's varStatus as an ID

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I want to use the count from the JSTL forEach loop, but my code doesnt seem to work.

```
<c:forEach items="${loopableObject}" var="theObject" varStatus="theCount">
    <div id="divIDNo${theCount}">
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

produces

```
<div id="divIDNojavax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@5570e2" >
```

Comment: Here is the class' javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html Look what getter methods it offers. Yes, among others there's a `getIndex()` :)

Answer (score 268, accepted):

The variable set by `varStatus` is a [`LoopTagStatus`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) object, not an int. Use:

```
<div id="divIDNo${theCount.index}">
```

To clarify:

- `${theCount.index}` starts counting at `0` unless you've set the `begin` attribute
- `${theCount.count}` starts counting at `1`

Comment: `${theCount.count}` **always** starts at 1. `${theCount.index}` starts at whatever you have set the `begin` attribute to. e.g. `<c:forEach var="foo" items="${bar}" begin="5" varStatus="theCount">`

Answer (score 10):

you'd use any of these:

JSTL c:forEach varStatus properties

Property    Getter  Description

- current  getCurrent()    The item (from the   collection) for the current
  round of iteration.
- index    getIndex()  The   zero-based index for the current round of
  iteration.
- count    getCount()  The one-based count for the current round of    iteration
- first    isFirst()   Flag indicating whether the current round 
  is the first pass through the iteration
- last isLast()    Flag   indicating    whether the current round is the last pass through the   iteration
- begin    getBegin()  The value of the begin attribute
- end  getEnd()    The    value of the end attribute
- step getStep()   The value of the step   attribute

Answer (score 6):

You can try this. similar result

```
 <c:forEach items="${loopableObject}" var="theObject" varStatus="theCount">
    <div id="divIDNo${theCount.count}"></div>
 </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its really helped me to dynamically generate ids of `showDetailItem` for the below code.

```
<af:forEach id="fe1" items="#{viewScope.bean.tranTypeList}" var="ttf" varStatus="ttfVs" > 
<af:showDetailItem  id ="divIDNo${ttfVs.count}" text="#{ttf.trandef}"......>
```

if you execute this line `<af:outputText value="#{ttfVs}"/>` prints the below:

> {index=3, count=4, last=false, first=false, end=8, step=1, begin=0}

Comment: @HenryKeiter there is a real answer here.  Bad formatting just had all the html hidden until I fixed it.

Comment: This provides the exact same answer as was already provided 3 years earlier (use `varStatus.count`), only much less readable. Why bother reading other people's answers? ;)